# How to stop Remote Desktop causing PgAdminIII windows to be black

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, windows-server-2012-r2, postgresql

We have a new server (2012 R2), at the moment it doesn't do anything and I'm using it to test some SQL by running pgAdmin.

I access this using both standard remote desktop and remote desktop connection manager but have problems where the (only the pgAdmin) window goes black when I have more that a couple of pgAdmin windows open (had to orange box some bits, so ignore those). It stops being black if I make the window smaller (to about just under 1/4 screen size) and parts of the screen (e.g buttons) appear when I click on them.

[image]

I know MS made a lot of changes to RDP for 2012 and wondered if that was the reason or if anyone else experience this? How can I stop this from happening?

I am running the RDCM 2.2b2.462 and RD v? (whatever comes with win7, fully updated).
I've tried a windows 8 r2 client and experience the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

First I would remove RDCM from the picture and try to resolve the problem using the built-in Remote Desktop Connection client (mstsc.exe).

Try reducing the resolution of the RDP session (RDC client -> Display -> Size).

Try increasing the color-depth of the RDP session (RDC client -> Display -> Colors -> "Highest Quality (32-bit)" ).

Comment: I'll give it a go, but I have the problem on mstsc as well. These are very powerful computers/servers though.

Answer (score 1):

One of the changes to 2012 RDP, is the data stream can be split into both TCP and UDP on port 3389.
If you have some sort of firewall only allowing 3389 TCP, some things work "funny".
You could try and ensure that 3389 UDP is accessible, and see if it fixes the problem.

This is purely guesswork since your network setup is not described, but it could fit the bill.

Comment: Quite possibly, the server is in a DC and behind all sorts of devices. Strange that it would be a problem just with pgAmin though? I'll check, thanks.